# open a new Window and print that new Window by Event (IE)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, event-handling

i want to open a new Window with a link and Print that window (by window.print()) after an event is triggered. That code work well with Chrome and FF but it dosnt work with IE:

```
function printClick(){
    var link = makeLink();
    var win = window.open(link, '_blank');
    win.focus();

    if(!win.addEventListener){
        win.attachEvent('myEvent', function (e) {
            win.print();
        },false);
    }else{
        win.addEventListener('myEvent', function (e) {
            win.print();
        }, false);
    }
}
```

The new window "var win" itself initialized the event by:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    myEvent= document.createEvent("Event");
    myEvent.initEvent("myEvent", true, false);
}
```

and trigger the event with this line:

```
    window.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

It looks like the Event is dispatched but the Listener (attachEvent) dont do anything.
Have i done something wrong with the Events? I have tested it with IE11.
If you miss any information to answer the question feel free to ask. =)

Thank You

Comment: Browser detection is usually bad if you really want feature detection. Can you replace your `isIE()` with `!!window.Event` or some similar feature check? Does one of the variants work in IE or does it not work at all?

Comment: a feature detection, i will hold that in mind; i Have placed a debugger; to check if IE got any problems with the code (Errors) all looked fine, but it did not open the print View...

Comment: ok i have add the Feature detection, it still work with FF and Chrome but IE dont want to open the printview / trigger the Event

Comment: Do you get an errors?

Comment: IE dont throw any Errors =/

Comment: Maybe IE doesn't like you sending events across windows. Do you absolutely needs events are can you do a direct function call? You can also consider using `window.postMessage` to send messages to other windows.

Comment: no i do not absolutely need the event across windows ... i now have add the Listener to the ready function of the new Window, that worked well for alle browsers, thank you.